# JAX-RS refactor sub-resource into separate Resource class?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Can a JAX-RS (Jersey) Resource class with a sub-resource be split into two classes?

Currently, I have the two combined into a single resource class:

```
@Path("/session")
public class SessionResource {

    @POST
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response createSession() {
        ...
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.created(URI.create("/session/" + new Date().toString()));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @DELETE
    public Response destroySession() {
        ...
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.noContent();
        return builder.build();        
    }

    // TrustedSession sub-resource

    @POST
    @Path("/trusted")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response createTrustedSession() {
        ...
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.created(URI.create("/session/" + new Date().toString()));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/trusted")
    public Response destroyTrustedSession() {
        ...
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.noContent();
        return builder.build();        
    }    


}
```

I would like to move the TrustedSession code to a separate Resouce:

```
@Path("/session/trusted")
public class createSession {

        @POST
        @Produces("application/xml")
        public Response createTrustedSession() {
            ...
            ResponseBuilder builder = Response.created(URI.create("/session/trusted/" + new Date().toString()));
            return builder.build();

        }

        @DELETE
        public Response destroySession() {
            ...
            ResponseBuilder builder = Response.noContent();
            return builder.build();   

        }  
}
```

While the code compiles, the resource routing doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to process a sub-resource in a separate class, you have to omit the request method designator for the method in the main resource class.

Try to create a sub class for your trusted session. Return an instance of this class in the main resource class like this:

```
@Path("/session")
public class SessionResource {
    // Note that the request method designator is omitted.
    @Path("/trusted")
    public TrustedSession getTrustedSession() {
        return new TrustedSession();
    }    
}
```

In the class for the sub-resource, you just have to annotate the request methods:

```
public class TrustedSession {
    @POST
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response createTrustedSession() {
        URI uri = URI.create("/session/trusted/" + new Date().toString());
        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    public Response destroySession() {
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Sub resource locators are (briefly) explained in [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gknav.html#gkrhr).

By the way: URIs can be build more conveniently and safely with the javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder, namely with its method fromResource(Class).

Comment: The problem with `UriBuilder#fromResource(Class)` is it only works with **root resources**. In the above example, if you used `UriBuilder.fromResource(this.getClass())`  in `TrustedSession#createTrustedSession()`, it would throw an `IllegalStateException`. I'm yet to find an elegant solution for this.

Comment: I found a way to get this to work even from sub-resources. Posted the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854924/570930).