# How do I get the JAX-RS @Path of a different resource during a POST?

Tags: java, rest, path, jersey, jax-rs

I have two REST classes for a simple web service (Jersey and GlassFish) that involves user resources - one to operate on all users (e.g., a factory for @POSTing) and another on individual users (e.g., @GET, @PUT, @DELETE). They are at:

```
@Stateless @Path("users") public class AllUsersResource {...}
@Stateless @Path("user") public class OneUserResource {...}
```

respectively. When POSTing to AllUsersResource I want to return the Location (via `Response.created(uri).build()`) of the new User, e.g.,

```
http://localhost:8080/.../user/152
```

My question is how to do this. AllUsersResource injects @Context UriInfo uriInfo, but that does not get me @Path info for OneUserResource, only that of the current call ("users"). The way I finally got it working was simply to use reflection, but I'm worried it is brittle and unclean:

```
OneUserResource.class.getAnnotation(Path.class).value();
```

Searching StackOverflow the only other things I found to try were the following, without success:

- com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceContext
- javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo.getMatchedResources()
- @javax.inject.Inject OneUserResource oneUserRes;

Any help would be terrific!

Comment: This old question was relevant to me today.  Be careful using the path annotation directly as there could be expressions or path parameters in there which would not translate directly into a path, E.G., "service/{username}", "service/{empId: [0-9]+}".

Answer (score 15):

You can use UriBuilder.fromresource(), but this only works if the supplied Resource class is a root resource (this is clearly mentioned in the javadocs). I found a way to achieve this even if you are in a sub-resource class:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION-XML, MediaType.APPLICATION-JSON})
public Response createUser(final User user, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    // persist the user here
    URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(user.getId()).build();
    return Response.created(uri).build();
}
```

Comment: this would return `http://localhost:8080/project/users/152` instead of `http://localhost:8080/project/user/152` while the latter is what is needed for SO

Answer (score 10):

I found a couple of javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder methods that did the trick, which I wanted to share in case others had this question. They are: UriBuilder.fromResource(OneUserResource.class) and javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.path(Class). I used the latter in a one-shot call:

```
URI newUserUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(OneUserResource.class).path("/" + user.getId()).build();
return Response.created(newUserUri).build();
```

Comment: The problem with both these methods is they both require **root** resource classes to work. They will not work if you use them from a sub-resource (`IllegalArgumentException` is thrown). So, if you used a sub-resource which handled the POST request; and you wanted to return a `201` with the `Location` header, you're still out of luck :(

Answer (score 5):

With the strict REST concept you can make it as one root resource

```
@POST   /users        -> CREATE a single user
@GET    /users        -> READ all users
@PUT    /users        -> UPDATE (REPLACE) all users @@?
@DELETE /users        -> DELETE all users @@?

@POST   /users/{id}   -> CREATE a single user's some other child; @@?
@GET    /users/{id}   -> READ a single user
@PUT    /users/{id}   -> UPDATE a single user
@DELETE /users/{id}   -> DELETE a single user
```

```java
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
public class UsersResouce {

    // /users
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION-XML, MediaType.APPLICATION-JSON})
    public Response createUser(final User user) {
        // persist the user here
        return Response.created("/" + user.getId()).build();
    }

    // /users
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION-XML, MediaType.APPLICATION-JSON})
    public Response readUsers() {
        //return all users
    }

    // /users/{id}
    @GET
    @Path("/{user_id: \\d+}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION-XML, MediaType.APPLICATION-JSON})
    public Response readUser(
        @PathParam("user_id") final Long userId) {

        final User persisted = userBean.find(userId);

        if (persisted == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

        return Response.ok().entity(persisted).build();
    }

    // /users/{id}
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION-XML, MediaType.APPLICATION-JSON})
    @PUT
    @Path("/{user_id: \\d+}")
    public Response updateUser(
        @PathParam("user_id") final Long userId,
        final User mergeable) {

        final User persisted = userBean.find(userId);

        if (persisted == null) {
            userBean.persist(mergeable);
        } else {
            persist.setName(mergeable.getName());
            userBean.merge(persisted);
        }

        return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }

    // /users/{id}
    @DELETE
    @Path("/{user_id: \\d+}")
    public Response deleteUser(
        @PathParam("user_id") final Long userId) {

        userBean.delete(userId);

        return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }

    @EJB
    private UserBean userBean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of JAX-RS 2.0, the most correct way (As far as I know) is to use the builder method like so:

```
    String uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
      .path(ODataV4Endpoint.class)
      .path(ODataV4Endpoint.class, "serviceEndpointJSONCatalog")
      .resolveTemplate("endpointId", endpointId).build().toString();
```

FYI, I need to call path twice in my case, once for the path annotation on the class, and the second time for the annotation on the method.  I suspected the call to the method would do both, but it does not.

The Path annotation on the endpoint serviceEndpointJSONCatalog declared a parameter, like so: 'endpoint/{endpointId}', so the call to resolveTemplate was needed.  Otherwise you would just call path(Class cl, String method).

In my case I created a builder and a symbolic way to reference the methods so the compiler / runtime could check them.