# Structuring REST URI's with Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

New to Jersey(REST Framework for Java) and I'm trying to setup two resources, in two separate classes that share a root path, and I'm having a problem. 
So, I have something like:

```
@Path("/users")
public class User extends RestSupport {

    @GET
    @Path("/{user_uuid}")
    public String get(@PathParam("user_uuid") String uuid) {    
        return "Hello User " + uuid;
    }
}
```

The above class works. However, I want to create a child resource in a separate class. But when I do this, it seems to create a URI naming conflict. So, here, I want to get all the pets for a particular users

```
@Path("/users")
public class Pets extends RestSupport {

    @GET
    @Path("/{user_uuid}/pets")
    public String get(@PathParam("user_uuid") String uuid) {    
        return "Hello Pets " + uuid;
    }
}
```

These top-level resources have lots of child resources, so I'm looking for the best way to organize them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073336/jax-rs-refactor-sub-resource-into-separate-resource-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the path of `Pets` class from 
`@Path("/users")`
to
`@Path("/users/{user_uuid}/pets")`

Comment: This seems like the obvious answer, and I tried to do this before posting. It failed with some sort of cryptic error; however, I gave this another go, made sure I cleaned my build, and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the HTTP annotation `@GET` on your `Users` root resource method if you want Jersey to delegate calls to a child resource. Consider a `User` class:

```java
public class User {

  String uuid;
  User(String id) { this.uuid = id; }

  @GET
  public String get() { return "Hello user " + uuid; }

  @GET
  @Path("/pets")
  public String getPets() { return "Hello pets " + uuid; }

}
```

and then adjust your `Users` resource:

```java
@Path("/users")
public class Users  {

  @Path("/{user_uuid}")
  public User get(@PathParam("user_uuid") String uuid) {
    // Get the user from the DAO here...
    return new User(uuid);
  }

}
```

Comment: whats interesting  to me is that there is no @Path on User. Does Jersey default the path to being the name of the class? What's the algorithm there? I've been trying to find that in Jersey documentation but I can't