# RESTful Hirerarchy with classes with JAXRS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

Would like to create the below hierarchical structure in REST with JAXRS and jersey as provider

```
@POST /origination/customers/
@PUT /origination/customers
@GET /origination/customers/{customerId}

@POST /origination/customers/{customerId}/inventory
@PUT /origination/customers/{customerId}/inventory
@GET /origination/customers/{customerId}/inventory/inventoryId
```

Currently all the services are written in a single class OriginationService, but for better encapsulation I would like to know if the services can be refractored like the customer origination in a seperate class called CustomerOriginationService and Inventory origination inside CustomerInventoryService (This is an example scenario, my problem is something similar)

Is it possible to achieve the above with JAXRS(Jersey) annotation

Comment: You might want to look at [Sub-Resource Locators](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2424)

Comment: That's almost what I'am looking for, thanks a ton (almost, cause yet to ascertain if it can handle all the usecases I have). Another Stackoverflow post in the same context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073336/jax-rs-refactor-sub-resource-into-separate-resource-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-resource locator is the keyword I was looking for.

The below article sums it up nicely
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gknav.html#gkrhr

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! Ant that's the standard way to assemble set of HTTP methods in different classes. You need to use `@Path` Example - `@Path("/{parameter}")`.

Below code may be useful to you -

Controller Interface -

```
package com.teducate.api;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public interface TekEvents {
    @GET
    @Path("/{parameter}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
            @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("value") String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;
}
```

Implementation -

```
package com.teducate.api.impl;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.teducate.api.TekEvents;
import com.teducate.bo.TekEventsBO;
import com.teducate.bo.impl.TekEventBOImpl;

@Path("events")
public class TekEventsController implements TekEvents {

    TekEventsBO tekEventsBO;

    public TekEventsController() {
        tekEventsBO = new TekEventBOImpl();
    }

    public Response responseMsg(String parameter, String value) {
        String output = tekEventsBO.responseMsg(parameter, value);
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```